# Request object exposing password check variable

Tags: cakephp, authentication

So in the sake of security I force all password change requests to validate through a password check. The problem I have is that using a `debug($this->request)` call I'm seeing a plaintext password:

```
object(CakeRequest) {
    ...snip...
    data => array(
        'User' => array(
            'password' => '*****',
            'password_check' => 'asdfa',
            'id' => '38'
        )
    )
    ...snip...
}
```

Should this be a concern for me? Is there a way I can have password_check treated like a password?

Comment: just don't leave debug mode on when you put your website live (and live === publically accessable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as you don't actually print it anywhere on the page you will be fine!

Comment: it answers the main question: "Should this be a concern for me?" => NO

Comment: ok fair enough I will remove the comment, it got flagged by SO